# JQuery - Get Absolute x,y position of a centered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, text-align

I want to find the left,top positions from an element. However, the parent container of this element has text-align: center; Therefore if there is a few on the bottom row, the first is 0px, rather than say, 450px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
offset = $( yourselectorhere ).offset()
```

Comment: @ bukfixart: Worth reading the **How to Format** stuff next to the answer box. Shows you how to format code properly, etc. Also, I added a link to the docs for the OP.